# version of .net framework launch not match .net framework bootstrapper project

Tags: vb.net-2010, setup-deployment, crystal-reports-2010

When I build the release project  of  the vb.net 2010 I just started using,  I get two warnings:

1. the version of the .net framedwork launch condition does not match the selected .net framework bootstrapper package.  Update the .net framewk launch condition to match the version of the .netfrk selected in the prerequisites dialog box.
2. The target version of the .net framework in the project does not match the .net framework launch condition version .net framework 4 client profile.  Update  the version of the .net framework launch condition to match the target version of the .net framework in the advanced compile options dialog box.

I changed the framework of the main project from client profile (which it was when I first created it) to frwk 4 because I read that crystal reports would not work with frwk 4 client profile.  (is that true).

The bootstrap version Framework is for x64 and x86.  I continued to look around the web and found that one can change the framework in the launch conditions  of the setup project. These seem to be scattered around in numerous places which is a problem I don't recall ever having with other verions of .net.  Anyway,   That solved that problem, but there is still another issue associated with this.

I have changed anycpu to x86 for the main project and the secondary projects  because I was having a problem with installing both msi's for crystal.  Meanwhile, the other secondary projects (which were upgraded from 2008) I changed to x86 but in the configuration file, it says anycpu for these and as has been written here, cannot be changed to x86.  I am not getting an error but have not yet tested whether the installation works.

I read an answer on your site to go into vbproj and change in notepad from x86 to x64 because they could not change from anycpu to x86 that way.  But I don't want x64 so not sure what to do.

It seems that anyCPU would be a good selection but will that work with Crystal and do I need to attach other than the x86 msi if I do change it?  Or can I leave it as is in this unclear situation.

Answer (score 15):

This error is because of a mismatch. You can fix it by making either one of them match the other.

One is the "Launch Condition."  The other is the "Prerequisite."

To change the Launch Condition:

- right click your setup project in the Solution Explorer
- click View - Launch Conditions
- select the ".NET Framework" item under Launch Conditions
- in the properties window, see the Version item. You can open the drop down menu to select the appropriate framework version.

To change the Prerequisite:

- right click your setup project in the Solution Explorer
- choose properties, a Properties Pages dialog appears
- click the "Prerequisites..." button
- check and uncheck framework versions as appropriate

Answer (score 5):

Yet another poorly documented feature from our friends at Microsoft. With the Setup project selected there are an array of icons in the solution explorer toolbox; one of which is "Launch Condition Editor".

Select the setup project, select the "Launch Condition Editor", new window opens. Select "Launch Conditions", ".Net Framework" Look at properties, version. Select the present version, opens drop down menu, select desired framework.

Rebuild.

(Thanks to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5167197a-12a5-473e-940a-569e92f08f37/error-the-version-of-the-net-framework-launch-condition-net-framework-4-does-not-match-the)

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I ran into this issue as well. There are 3 places I found that need to match. Not 2 places. I am using VS2015 with the Add-in Setup Project available from Microsoft.

Place 1: Target Framework needs to be what you are targeting, variable X. To get to this go to the properties of your main project and select the target framework for your code.

Place 2: Right click your setup project and go to view > Launch conditions, click .Net Framework, and in the properties window select your target framework... variable X.

Place 3: Right click your setup project and go to properties > Prerequisites. This will show the pre-requisite from the program... In my case Variable X needed to match what was checked in this box.

This resulted in a successful build of the project without the warning.